# Converting csv to .avro using PySpark - missing dependencies

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, avro

I have a Python script that uses the `fastavro` library to convert a csv file and serializes it according to the provided schema:

```
from fastavro import writer
from fastavro.schema import load_schema
import csv

schema = load_schema('schema.avsc')

def csv_reader():
    with open('data.csv') as f:
        yield from csv.DictReader(f)
with open('data.snappy.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, schema, csv_reader(), codec='snappy')
```

The above works just fine on small files, but is **terribly slow** on larger files. A 185MB sized csv file took 4.5 minutes to serialize and some of my files are nearing 5GB in size.

So, I thought I'd test and see how Spark handles csv to avro conversions using PySpark 2.4.3:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro, to_avro

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Avro testing") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = open("schema.avsc", "r").read()

df = spark.read.csv(path="/data/data.csv",
                    header=True)
output = df\
  .select(from_avro("value", schema).alias("user"))\
  .where('user.favorite_color == "red"')\
  .select(to_avro("user.name").alias("value"))
```

but this returns the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.sql.avro'

Ok, I get that the avro library is not included by default and it makes sense that I'm getting the error.

The Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#deploying) suggests running `./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2 ...` but I'm not running spark-submit directly on the command line - it's being called from my Python code.

My question is: how do I modify my Python code so that the Spark job is still called from the code but also includes the missing external avro library at `pyspark.sql.avro`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're looking for an environment variable

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2' 

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Avro testing") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

However, if you're reading a CSV file, you shouldn't be using `from_avro`

If you want to convert a CSV into Avro, you'd **only** want `to_avro`

And if you're only running this locally, on one machine, I'd be surprised if Spark would be any faster than the plain Python approach